# How to restrict merge permission for the author of the pull request on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

My team wants to restrict merge permissions to only the reviewers. Once a pull request is approved, only the default approvers must be given an option to merge the code. Currently, the author of the pull request also has the permission to merge the code. How do I restrict this permission.

I am trying to work with "Script Merge Checks" hook on BitBucket Server, but don't really have an idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Branch Permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html).

Set **Prevent all changes** restriction and add all your default reviewers here as well.